Why do the eigenvalues of the sum of matrices add up in my example?
I am examining the following matrix: $C= \begin{bmatrix} -A & A \\ B & -B\end{bmatrix}$, where $A$ and $B$ are positive definite diagonal matrices with both having the same dimension $n$.
Interestingly, in all examples which I tested the spectrum for C is the following: $\sigma(C)= \{ - (a_{11} + b_{11}), - (a_{22} + b_{22}), \ldots, - (a_{nn} + b_{nn}) , 0, \ldots, 0 \}$ with $a_{ii}$ and $b_{ii}$ being i-th diagonal element of $A$ resp. $B$. The eigenvalue zero appears $n$-times.
My approach is the following:
$\begin{bmatrix} -A & A \\ B & -B\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \otimes A + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix} \otimes B$.
Clearly the first matrix has the spectrum $\{-\sigma(A),0, \ldots, 0\}$ with n zero eigenvalues and the same applies for the second matrix but with $B$ instead of $A$. Now it seems that both spectra can simply be added together and I cannot explain why. Can anyone help me?
As an example $A = 1$, $B = 2$ leads to $\sigma(C)= \{ -3,0\}$ and the same applies for higher dimensional examples.

It's easy to construct the eigenvectors for $C$.  For the zero eigenvalues you just have a 1 in the ith and (n+i)th place and zeroes elsewhere.  For the non-zero eigenvalues you have 1 in the ith place, and a -1 in the (n+i)th place.  The algebra on these eigenvectors yields this result.

@Paul the arguement considering the zero eigenvalue is correct but even for the stated example the eigenvector for the non-zero eigenvalue of C is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$ and not [1 -1]

Ah, you're right.  Constructing the non-zero eigenvalue's eigenvector is a little more complicated.  I had the transpose of your matrix in your head--but note that this is a back door way to get there, since the transpose of a matrix has the same eigenvalues as the original.

If all you want are the eigenvalues then you just have look at $\det (C-xI)$. A few row/column operations [using the block structure] reduces this to $\det(\begin{pmatrix} -xI & O\O& (A+B)-xI\end{pmatrix}$. This is true for all $A,B$. But there is a perfectly good answer given already.

Consider the matrix $C^T = \begin{bmatrix} -A & B\\ A & -B \end{bmatrix}$, which has the same spectrum as $C$. Denote a vector as $z=(v|w)$, where both $v$ and $w$ are of length $n$. Then $z$ is an eigenvector if and only if there exists $\lambda\in k$ such that \begin{cases} -Av+Bw=\lambda v \\ Av-Bw=\lambda w \end{cases}
If $\lambda = 0 $ then the two rows of the system are equivalent and we have $n$ equations in $2n$ variables, hence $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(C^T)) \geq n$. This tells us that there are at least $n$ zeros in the spectrum.
If we set $\lambda \neq 0$ then the only possibility is $w=-v$ and the system reduces to $-(A+B)v = \lambda v$. In particular, the (non-zero) eigenvalues of $C^T$ are the same as $-(A+B)$.

Thanks for the reply! Is this applicable also for other matrices than my assumed diagonal matrices? I am asking because I observed that if A and B are both upper triangular matrices it also seems to hold. How ever if A is an upper triangular and B is a lower triangular matrix it seems not to hold anymore.

My argument does not involve any particular shape for A or B, and it always follow that the non-zero part of the spectrum of C is given by the spectrum of -(A+B).
